# JQuery UI Dialog textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to put a textarea inside a JQuery UI dialog box.  I want to prepopulate this text area with a value.  If I use `<textarea>` the dialog box does not even open.  However, if I change it to `<input type="text"`> then my dialog box works just fine.  I'm not sure if the issue is with the `<textarea>` itself or putting in the value.  Here is my code.  The issue is the textarea with id "change_dialog_msg". Even just using `<textarea></textarea>` still causes the dialog box not to open.
The dialog box is being opened from a table with the following code (the exact same code works on another page in my application so I don't think the issue is with that).

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="OpenDialog(<bean:write name='cel' property='id' scope="page"/>);return false;">View/Modify</a>

<div id="change_dialog" title="Change Email Message" style="display: none; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">
            <div style="text-align: left;">
                <br>
                Change the expiration email message for Course ID: "<span id="change_dialog_courseName"></span>".
                <br>
                <font color="red">Please enter %fn for first name, %ln for last name, %dt for expiration date, %gn for group, %cn for curriculum, and %sn for stage number.</font>
                <br><br>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="change_dialog_msg"/>
                <br><br>
            </div>
            <button id="change" onclick="ChangeBtn();return false;">Submit</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id="delete" onclick="DeleteBtn();return false;">Delete</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id="cancel" onclick="CancelBtn();return false;">Cancel</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var currId = -1;
            $("#change_dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: "auto",
                modal: true,
                resizable: false
            });//.siblings('div.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
            function OpenDialog(id){
                currId = id;
                $("#change_dialog_courseName").text(courseIDs[id]);
                $("#change_dialog_msg").val(emailMSG[id]);
                $("#change_dialog").dialog("open");
            }
            function ChangeBtn(){
                if(/\S/.test($("#change_dialog_msg").val())){
                    $("#newEmailMSG").val($("#change_dialog_msg").val());
                    $("#id").val(currId);
                    $("#submitOpt").val("Change");
                    $("#emailSettings").submit();
                } else {
                    alert("You must enter a message when pressing submit.");
                }                
            }
            function CancelBtn(){
                currId = -1;
                $("#change_dialog_msg").val("");
                $("#change_dialog").dialog("close");
            }
            function DeleteBtn(){
                if($("#change_dialog_msg").val()==""){
                    $("#change_dialog").dialog("close");
                } else {
                    $("#id").val(currId);
                    $("#submitOpt").val("Delete");
                    $("#emailSettings").submit();
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't executed the whole code but I can say it would work after a little change -

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="change_dialog_msg"/>
```

to

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="change_dialog_msg"></textarea>
```

Thanks.